# How to lock section of a row after data entry

Tags: excel, vba

I’ve spent a considerable part of my morning in vba in Excel using bits and pieces of codes I’ve come across through this site but I’m having no luck now. I’ve managed to get a few complicated (or complicated to me anyway, I’m definitely no expert!) parts working but I’ve hit a brick wall here.

We’re creating a sheet for staff to enter information into. It currently has 19 headed columns (A – S) and staff data entry begins on Row 20. There are 2500 Rows.

What we’re trying to achieve is that when staff reach Column L of their row and input data into it, that specific row becomes password protected between cells A-L. M-S should still be editable but A-L should be locked down to editing.

The lock should only impact the row the user is working on. So the next user can enter their information on the row below, and again it’ll lock on L, repeating this right down to 2500.

Everything I’ve tried so far has resulted in the entire worksheet being locked upon entry in L. The closest I’ve been to my goal is managing to get one row to lock on data entry in L, but it locked the entire row, not just A-L (then I got locked out and had to start again).

It would be handy if there was a pop up box warning the user that entering data in L will lock the preceding cells, but it’s not vital and I can write a note at the top.

Any ideas? I’ve been going in circles for what feels like hours.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Target.Column = 12 Then 
        Range("A21,B21,C21,D21,E21,F21,G21,H21,I21,J21,K21,L21").Locked = True 
        ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've been playing around with the following recently, but it's locking the entire document instead of A-L. I also know it wont impact rows 22 > 2500 but I was hoping if I could get it working on one line I could expand it.   
  
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
      If Target.Column = 12 Then
        Range("A21,B21,C21,D21,E21,F21,G21,H21,I21,J21,K21,L21").Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
      End If

    End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could start with something like this :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"
    Dim Row As Long
    If Target.Column = 12 Then
        Target.Parent.Unprotect PASSWORD
        Row = Target.Row
        Target.Parent.Range("A" & Row & ":" & "L" & Row).Locked = True
        Target.Parent.Protect PASSWORD
    End If
End Sub
```

This code has to be inserted in the worksheet you want to protect.

Comment: Also, as a complement to my previous answer, you should know that locking is applied both to cell level and sheet level. By default, each cell is "locked". You have to manually unlock the range from A20 to L1048576. This can be done after rightclicking on the aforementioned range>Cell format>Protection then untick "Locked".

Comment: Excellent, thank you! It's behaving perfectly now. This really helped so thanks again for this.